# Angularjs dependency injection inside factory

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement error logging, by following this tutorial:
http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/

Errors are logged fine, but i have problems when i want to send the log to the server. I cant make http request. I tried:

```
   $.ajax({type: "POST"...})
```

But is says that $ is not defined.
Also i tried to inject $http here:

```
loggingModule.factory( "exceptionLoggingService", ["$log","$window", "traceService","$http"...
```

But then i receive this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep?p0=$rootScope%20%3C-%20$http%20%3C-%20errorLogService%20%3C-%20$exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20$rootScope).
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.ajax() is a jQuery function. You're using AngularJS. So that's not surprising.

You have a circular dependency. This means that your exceptionLoggingService depends on $http, and $http depends (transitively) on exceptionLoggingService. To solve this error, you can lookup the $http service dynamically instead of having it injected:

```
loggingModule.factory('exceptionLoggingService', ['$injector', ..., function($injector, ...) {

    var sendErrorToServer = function(error) {
        $http = $injector.get('$http');
        $http.post(...);
    }
}
```

Note that there is still a circular dependency, which can cause problems is the logger is called when $http fails: that would call the logger to use $http, which would fail, which would cause the logger to be called, etc. etc.

Comment: even though question is irrelevant, i was able to learn issues related circular dependencies with this answer.. Thanks..